# Upgrading MVC 4 to MVC 5 connection issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I just upgraded all my mvc 4 project to mvc 5 (entity also upgraded to v6) - via nuget.

Now I get this error when trying to run the app:

> Cannot find the object "dbo.User" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions

Why this is happening now? one minute ago (before upgrade) it was working. How to solve?

Comment: The default user management in mvc 4 was Simple Membership Provider. In 5, it changed to Identity. This could be part of the issue you are experiencing. I am not sure of the conversion process.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 5 switched from using the classic Membership tables (*i.e. dbo.User*) to the new ASP.NET Identity. Would this be a breaking change for your application?

Comment: @William that table was created by me. Just a User table. Is that generating some conflict? How do I check that asp.net Identity?

Comment: @Fabricio [Here](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2014/02/migrating-existing-website-from_16.html)'s the blog post I referenced when migrating my Membership from MVC4 to MVC5.

Answer (score 1):

There is more to upgrading than just using Nuget.  Did you follow the migration process?

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

Answer (score 0):

Check your database connection string. Some packages edit web.config so it makes sense to make sure nothing obvious changed there.